# Issue connecting to token server with Firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, twilio-video

I am trying to deploy the Twilio video app to Firebase hosting. Everything works great, except when I try to connect to video conference it tells me the Twilio tokens are invalid.

I found that I need to set up google cloud functions to resolve this. How do you go about converting a server.js file to a cloud function?

Here is my code server.js code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;
require('dotenv').config();

const MAX_ALLOWED_SESSION_DURATION = 14400;
const twilioAccountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const twilioApiKeySID = process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID;
const twilioApiKeySecret = process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/token', (req, res) => {
  const { identity, roomName } = req.query;
  const token = new AccessToken(twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKeySID, twilioApiKeySecret, {
    ttl: MAX_ALLOWED_SESSION_DURATION,
  });
  token.identity = identity;
  const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({ room: roomName });
  token.addGrant(videoGrant);
  res.send(token.toJwt());
  console.log(`issued token for ${identity} in room ${roomName}`);
});

app.get('*', (_, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html')));

app.listen(8081, () => console.log('token server running on 8081'));
```

I'm thinking I can move that to the cloud functions index.js file and add the following to still connect to my .env file variables if I put the express function in here:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const config = functions.config();
// Porting envs from firebase config
for (const key in config.envs){
  process.env[key.toUpperCase()] = config.envs[key];
}
```

Comment: Here is the link to the Twilio repo I'm using: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react

Answer (score 1):

To convert this to a [Firebase cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), you need to remove server listeners and you have to setup a local Firebase environment to deploy and develop

#### Steps to convert cloud function

```sh
# Install firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools

# Login and initialize project
firebase login

firebase init functions

# For local dev
firebase serve 

# Deploy the function to cloud
firebase deploy
```

> Your current code will look something like this after converting to cloud function

You can also make each routes into separate modules

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const AccessToken = require('twilio').jwt.AccessToken;
const VideoGrant = AccessToken.VideoGrant;
require('dotenv').config();
const router = express.Router();

const MAX_ALLOWED_SESSION_DURATION = 14400;
const twilioAccountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const twilioApiKeySID = process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SID;
const twilioApiKeySecret = process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY_SECRET;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

router.get('/token', (req, res) => {
  const { identity, roomName } = req.query;
  const token = new AccessToken(twilioAccountSid, twilioApiKeySID, twilioApiKeySecret, {
    ttl: MAX_ALLOWED_SESSION_DURATION,
  });
  token.identity = identity;
  const videoGrant = new VideoGrant({ room: roomName });
  token.addGrant(videoGrant);
  res.send(token.toJwt());
  console.log(`issued token for ${identity} in room ${roomName}`);
});

router.get('*', (_, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html')));
// Your cloud function will be like : https://<region>-<appname>.cloudfunctions.net/twilioApp
exports.twilioApp = functions.https.onRequest(router);
```

> Please read the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

Comment: I'll give this a try - I'm still learning and so thank you for your help!